# Running two models in the same notebook

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run two models in the same notebook, but before that I had them in separate notebooks. The problem is that now that they are on the same notebook the values of the variables are different but the value of the objective function remains the same (compared with the values when the models were separate) . Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: What models are these?

Comment: Hi Mus, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide the source/notebook that you talk about? It would help, to help you.